# Parse Period Year from Header To Place in File Name

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I'm trying to parse the Period and Year from the header of the data file...

"Account ID","NetChangeJan*2018"

And place it in the file name (i.e. GL_Jan_2018.txt).

I've tried various FOR statements, but not having any luck.

```
For /F "eol=_ tokens=1 delims=," %%a in ('dir /b *.txt') do set filemonth=%%~na 
For /F "eol=_ tokens=2 delims=*" %%a in ('dir /b *.txt') do set yy=%%~na
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: @user7571572, edit your question and put your code in there.  Then delete your comment.